# Removed implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1' Communication to Firebase Stopped

Tags: android, firebase

I removed:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
```

to resolve a duplicate class issue between modules:

```
jetified-firebase-measurement-connector-impl-17.0.2-runtime.jar
```

and

```
play-services-measurement-api-17.2.1-runtime.jar
```

Once i did that the app compiled, but it would not connect to Firebase.

If i put it back, i get the error and the system does not compile.

If i remove the:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

the system won't compile but it will communicate with Firebase and it will still have the errors.

Trying to figure out how to resolve so it will both compile on Android Studio and connect with Firebase.

Comment: do you want to use firebase analytics? Or other firebase product?

Comment: i am trying to use the analytics portion of firebase and the database itself.